# Make an html form secure with https

Tags: php, javascript, html, https

Now, I know on the question of security it lingers in the back of our heads on every line of code we type. I have recently removed myself and my  company from using online form builders and went to coding all of our forms ourselves. The one really nice feature of online form builders was all the forms were secured with HTTPS.

I am wanting to know the exact steps one must take to make a self-coded form using HTML, Javascript, PHP, and CSS. HTTPS secure.

I know that no matter what we do to make an online form secure it will never be 100% guarnteed to NEVER get hacked and nothing is ever 100% fool proof. I am just wanting my visitors to know we are doing our part in protecting the information they are providing us online.

Thank you and any constructive help is appreciated!

Comment: this question is probably more well-suited for http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question: but as long as you follow one rule, you should be all right:

- **Don't trust ANY user input**

Any input coming from any user must be considered dangerous. Therefore, it must be sanitized before used. Any sanitation must be performed on the server-side, since the user can manipulate your javascript (or just disable it).

To prevent your data from being spied on by someone else on the network, use `HTTPS`. You sholdn't just use HTTPS on pages who use forms, but instead **on the whole website**.

Comment: Also as a side note if using cookies you might want to add http only flag and/or https/secure flag cookie

Comment: @Class Feel free to add this to the answer, and perhaps why this is a good idea :-).

Answer (score 0):

The components are Data in Transit, Your Web application, and the data in store that should be secured. For the data in transit use HTTPS, for the data in store you should encrypt it, and for the web application security should be considered during development life-cycle.

Before saving the data into DB:

- Check from token before processing it.
- Filter all user-input.
- Use prepared statement (PDO and mysqli)